# Export an animated 3D model to Power Point

Tags: animation

As you might have seen, it is now possible to insert an animated 3d object, like a walking T-Rex, into PowerPoint.

[image]

See for example: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-animated-3d-graphics-6f08009a-3da5-400d-a706-8e23f304cd72

Now, I am wondering, how can I create custom 3d models for powerpoint that would also have embedded animations like the T-rex has?

I have not found anything on the web so far. Most of the topics discuss how to create static 3d models for PP, but not how to create 3D models with embedded "scenes" or pre-set animations. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can export from Blender using fbx format. Though for the animation to be played in Powerpoint this is for rigged 3D models only (models animated by an armature). Have a look here (end of step 1) https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/new-play-animated-3d-models-in-word-and-powerpoint/f02513ff-ea35-4f85-b73d-93e4c9bef91b

Comment: @lemon Very Interesting. Have you tried it before? If so, would you mind sharing the steps of how to do it as an answer and maybe add some screen-shots or gifs of the final result? This would help me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Just make the animation you want and export it as mentioned... above that this site is not about making tutorials from scratch...

Comment: But I can confirm that fbx and glb formats are ok.

Comment: @lemon I understand, no problem. Okay, so far I have tried fbx. Seems to be working, but the texture is missing.

Comment: @lemon If I do a very simple animation, i.e. I just displace something (keyframe: location) and then export as fbx, the animation is not found in PP. Do you have any idea of how to make it work ? Many Thanks.

Comment: As said before it can work only for animations that are done using armatures (read carefuly the link indicated in the first comment).

Comment: @lemon  Many thanks for your answer. I am quite new to Blender, so please excuse my question, but do you see a way to do the displacement animation using armatures. I was thinking of using invisible objects... What do you think ?

Comment: Henry, I'm sorry but learning this kind of things is not the purpose of BSE. Try to google "blender beginner armature" so you'll have some explanations like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0btZFIeGtY

Comment: @lemon I see, many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/3d-content-guidelines-for-microsoft-03a7b493-d549-4f1a-9735-f2457adf6261?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) for a quick overview and at the [3D Content Guidelines for Microsoft powerpoint](http://aka.ms/3DContentGuidelines) for details.  As the 3D engine in Powerpoint is now based off [Babylon.js](https://www.babylonjs.com/) GLTF format is your best bet to get content to import correctly.

[image]
[image]